# Redmine spent time tracking restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

We recently installed **Redmine** in our organization.

I would like to know how to only allow a user to track spent time only for past `3 days`.

e.g. If today is `21 May 2018` then a user can only track time for `18,19,20 & 21 May 2018`. A user can not track time for `15th May 2018`

There are any plugins on need to add validation in database script or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any plugin for this specific purpose - but it would be easy to write one. It boils down to adding custom validation to `TimeEntry` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added to our in-house Redmine plugin a validation to restrict `TimeEntry#hours` to 8 hours. The actual lines are just a standard ActiveRecord validation:

```
    base.class_eval do
      validate :revalidate_time_entry
    end
```

...

```
    def revalidate_time_entry
      if hours && hours >= 0 && hours < 1000  #  Dodge the original validation
        errors.add :hours, :invalid if hours > 8
      end
    end
```

The `base.class_eval` is part of a patch on the TimeEntry class, in a plugin. Download nearly any Redmine plugin and read its ./lib/*/patches folder to learn how to patch. You need a validation on your `spent_on` field that it is `> 3.days.ago`.

Here's an example of a Redmine plugin that patches TimeEntry and adds a validation:

https://searchcode.com/file/11439509/tags/0.1/lib/cmi/time_entry_patch.rb

Ask here if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: Thanks, Phlip. I am not Ruby Rails developer but I know another programming. Should I need ruby rails expert or I can do it. Can you please share links or something else to integrate with Redmine.

Comment: I added more verbiage